# Configuring nuget path for msbuild on GitLab Runner

Tags: .net, gitlab, msbuild, nuget, gitlab-ci

So I am trying to create a CI pipeline in GitLab. For our .NET project, we are making use of powershell scripts to invoke/start the build process.
So we have an initial powershell file, which invokes the msbuild.exe. Currently it tries building the project like below:
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\build\build.xml /t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False

But since this is a .NET project, it also requires a nuget reference or a nuget.config file to load all the package dependencies. I tried to supply the path for the nuget.config file like below:

Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\build\build.xml /t:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=true **/p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\Users\ABCD.nuget\nuget.config"** /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False

but seems like the GitLab runner is still not reading the nuget.config file because its still throwing all the nuget package reference errors when it invokes the msbuild command.

Any inputs or workaround for this scenario please?

I tried to supply the path for nuget.config file as an argument to the msbuild command, which did not help.